# C# function is excuting twice but only once

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using `AutoUpdater.Net` and I start the check on the application launch (this one work well). A second time from the MainWindow.

This is the function that I call :

```
public void CheckUpdate()
{
    if (IsConnectedToInternet())
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
        Update.InstalledVersion = new Version(fvi.FileVersion);
        Update.Synchronous = true;
        //comment the line below to show the AutoUpdater.NET forms
        Update.CheckForUpdateEvent += AutoUpdaterOnCheckForUpdateEvent;
        Update.Start("http:/myurl/");
    }
    else
        IminaDialog.ShowMessage("Update error", "It seems you're not connected to internet.", ModalWindowButtons.Ok);
}
```

And the function `AutoUpdateOnCheckForUpdateEvent` is executing twice. It come to the last line of the method and directly restart the method. The call stack from the loading or from the `MainWindow` still the same. From the `MainWindow` I call it from the `Instance` of the parent class.
I hope someone can help and tell me if you want more informations.

**EDIT**

This is the call that execute twice `AutoUpdateOnCheckForUpdateEvent` (`CheckUpdate` execute once every time):

```
        public static WpfCommand CommandCheckUpdate
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_commandCheckUpdate == null) 
            {
                _commandCheckUpdate = new WpfCommand();
                _commandCheckUpdate.Executed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    FrameworkController.Instance.CheckUpdate();
                };
            }
            return _commandCheckUpdate;
        }
    }
```

If I only call `FrameworkController.Instance` the `CheckUpdate` don't execute.
And here it's were the method is called on load (inside `FrameworkController`) :

```
public void Start(string[] mainArgs)
    {
        InitializeLog();

        if (!License.RegisterLicense(null))
            return;

        DefaultMenuItems.PopulateMenuService(MenuService.Instance);
        IminaUtils.Initialize(); // Initialize helper methods

        CheckUpdate();

        _firstConfigurationLoading = Configuration.Load();

        MainWindowViewModel.ClearDiagnostic();
        if (RightRepository.Instance.CurrentUser == null)
            MainWindowViewModel.OpenLogin();

        if (Configuration.ShutdownApp)
            return;

        ConnectConfiguration(mainArgs);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling CheckUpdate() twice, because that would add the event handler twice and that would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I call it like that : 
`public static WpfCommand CommandCheckUpdate
        {
            get 
            {
                if (_commandCheckUpdate == null) 
                {
                    _commandCheckUpdate = new WpfCommand();
                    _commandCheckUpdate.Executed += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        FrameworkController.Instance.CheckUpdate();
                    };
                }
                return _commandCheckUpdate;
            }
        }`

Comment: @JustinVuffray that is unreadable, i think it would make more sense to add it to the question, no?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line Update.CheckForUpdateEvent += AutoUpdaterOnCheckForUpdateEvent; and see if that is hit twice, if it is that is the root of your problem.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I edit my post

Comment: @Stefan That's it. If I execute a third time it start 3 times XD